# Greedy Algorithm - Depreciating Cost

Tags: algorithm, math, optimization, analysis, greedy

This is a problem I found as an extra note in Algorithm Design by Kleinberg and Tardos.

Suppose we are trying to sell off equipment whose cost is depreciating at a factor of r<sub>i</sub> < 1 per month, starting from $100, so if you sell it t months from now you will receive 100.r<sub>i</sub><sup>t</sup>.

If you can sell only one item per month what is the optimal order in which to sell them?

Input (3/4; 1/2; 1/100)

Optimal order would be [100x{1/2+(3/4)<sup>2</sup>+(1/100)<sup>3</sup>}].

I am not sure how to go about this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose there are N items with individual Ri.

1. Compute the N x N matrix where Cij = Power(Ri,j).
2. The problem now boils down to Assignment problem with N objects to be placed in N positions and each having corresponding profits associated.
3. Maximize the total profit using any algorithm like the Hungarian Algorithm.

Comment: I guess this is advanced. I was looking for a greedy algorithm. I am not able to evaluate/verify your answer. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Greedy method should work. Each month sell the item that maximizes Ri^month - Ri^(month+1). This means we sell the item that would lose the most value during the next month.

In the example input:

- 1/2 ^ 1 - 1/2 ^ 2 = 0.25
- 3/4 ^ 1 - 3/4 ^ 2 = 0.1875
- 1/100 ^ 1 - 1/100 ^ 2 = 0.0099

So first month we sell item with R = 1/2

- 3/4 ^ 2 - 3/4 ^ 3 = 0.046875
- 1/100 ^ 2 - 1/100 ^ 3  = 0.000099

R = 3/4 as the second item and 1/100 last.

I'm no mathematician so i can't give you a proof, but it's pretty clear this works if you accept that functions of the form a^x-a^(x+1) = b^x-b^(x+1) have only one solution.

Comment: Looks like this might work. Without proof Greedy algorithm hardly is accepted to be an optimal solution. I will try to work out a proof of correctness. Thanks.